Color code values conditionally in xlsx produced by openxlsx package in R in a loop
My reproducible code below writes a super small .xlsx file that has two sheets.
I was wondering if there might be a way to color-code values of 3 in red, 4 in orange, and 5 in green anywhere in the outputted .xlsx file?
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

list_data<- list(one= data.frame(District=LETTERS[1:3], V1 = 1:3),
                 two= data.frame(District=LETTERS[3:8], V7 = 3:8, V3=8:3))

write.xlsx(list_data, file="ColorCodeTest.xlsx", 
           rowNames=FALSE, firstRow =TRUE,
           gridLines=TRUE, borders="all", wrapText = FALSE, colWidths = "auto")


Openxlsx2 has a function to add conditional formatting. See the documentation here: https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx2/f/vignettes/conditional-formatting.Rmd

As mentioned in a comment, openxlsx2 changes how conditional formatting is added. Here is how you could apply this formatting in both openxlsx and openxlsx2:
openxlsx
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

list_data<- list(one= data.frame(District=LETTERS[1:3], V1 = 1:3),
                 two= data.frame(District=LETTERS[3:8], V7 = 3:8, V3=8:3))

Create a workbook, add worksheets, and write the data from your data frames
wb <- createWorkbook()

Map(function(data, sheetname){
  addWorksheet(wb, sheetname)
  writeData(wb, sheetname, data)
}, list_data, names(list_data))

Define the format styles
stylethree <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000", bgFill = "#EE1212")
stylefour <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000", bgFill = "#FFA500")
stylefive <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000", bgFill = "#22FD22")

Add the rules for formatting the worksheets
conditionalFormatting(wb, "one", cols = 1:2, rows = 1:4,
                      rule = '==3', style = stylethree)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "two", cols = 1:3, rows = 1:9,
                      rule = '==3', style = stylethree)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "one", cols = 1:2, rows = 1:4,
                      rule = '==4', style = stylefour)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "two", cols = 1:3, rows = 1:9,
                      rule = '==4', style = stylefour)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "one", cols = 1:2, rows = 1:4,
                      rule = '==5', style = stylefive)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "two", cols = 1:3, rows = 1:9,
                      rule = '==5', style = stylefive)

Save the notebook
saveWorkbook(wb, file = 'ColorCodeTest.xlsx', overwrite = TRUE)

openxlsx2
library(openxlsx2)

Create the workbook and add data
wb <- wb_workbook()

Map(function(data, sheetname){
  wb$add_worksheet(sheetname)
  wb$add_data(sheetname, data)
}, list_data, names(list_data))
#> $one
#> A Workbook object.
#>  
#> Worksheets:
#>  Sheets: one, two 
#>  Write order: 1, 2
#> $two
#> A Workbook object.
#>  
#> Worksheets:
#>  Sheets: one, two 
#>  Write order: 1, 2

Define format styles
wb$add_dxfs_style(name = 'style3',
                  font_color = wb_color(hex = "#000000"),
                  bg_fill = wb_color(hex = "#EE1212"))

wb$add_dxfs_style(name = 'style4',
                  font_color = wb_color(hex = "#000000"),
                  bg_fill = wb_color(hex = "#FFA500"))

wb$add_dxfs_style(name = 'style5',
                  font_color = wb_color(hex = "#000000"),
                  bg_fill = wb_color(hex = "#22FD22"))

Apply conditional formatting
wb$add_conditional_formatting("one",
                              dims = wb_dims(rows = 1:4, cols = 1:2),
                              style = 'style3',
                              rule = '==3')
wb$add_conditional_formatting("two",
                              dims = wb_dims(rows = 1:9, cols = 1:3),
                              style = 'style3',
                              rule = '==3')
wb$add_conditional_formatting("one",
                              dims = wb_dims(rows = 1:4, cols = 1:2),
                              style = 'style4',
                              rule = '==34')
wb$add_conditional_formatting("two",
                              dims = wb_dims(rows = 1:9, cols = 1:3),
                              style = 'style4',
                              rule = '==4')
wb$add_conditional_formatting("one",
                              dims = wb_dims(rows = 1:4, cols = 1:2),
                              style = 'style5',
                              rule = '==5')
wb$add_conditional_formatting("two",
                              dims = wb_dims(rows = 1:9, cols = 1:3),
                              style = 'style5',
                              rule = '==5')

Save the workbook
wb_save(wb, file = 'ColorCodeTest.xlsx', overwrite = TRUE)

